# Properties of the morphism $\mathbb A^1 \rightarrow \mathbb A^2$ given by $t\mapsto (t^2,t^3)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am given the morphism $\phi: \mathbb A^1 \rightarrow \mathbb A^2$ given (on closed points I guess) by $t\mapsto (t^2,t^3)$. Now I am supposed to check a few properties of this morphism:

quasi-finite, finite, proper, affine, projective and closed immersion.

My results so far:
It is quasi-finite, as it is injective on closed points.
It is affine as a morphism of affine schemes.
It is finite as the corresponding ring map is integral and of finite type (hence finite)
It is not a closed immersion, as the corresponding ring map is not surjective.

I am not sure about the properties projective and proper. My guess is that it is not universally closed, hence neither proper nor projective but I can't seem to prove this. Could you provide me with some hints and/or general strategies when approacing this plus the solution?

This is not for a homework problem, it is an exercise given on an exam from the previous years.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A finite morphism is always projective (and thus proper), see [here](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01WG). In your case, one can show this very explicitly. Namely, you can realize $\mathbb{A}^1$ as the blow up (see e.g. harris' book "algebraic geometry", page 80ff) of the image of $\phi$ at the origin, which is a closed subvariety of $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{A^2}$.

Comment: thank you very much! Earlier today I even proved that finite implies projective but this all is still quite new to me..^^